# Wordy IP for internal devices

Tags: networking, dns, ip

Hi I would like to have a ip to connect to devices on my network at home, however I don't want to have to remember lots of numbers instead I would like to have address that uses words. For example I can connect to my router using '192.168.1.254' or by using 'dsldevice.lan' How would I do this or what is it called as I can't find any info on it on the web. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: So, [hostname](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go to C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc and open the file called 'hosts' with notepad. Scroll to the bottom and add the line:

'IP Address' 'hostname'

for example:

```
192.168.1.20 Nasdrive
```

Then go to file and save. You will then be able to go to 192.168.1.20 using the word Nasdrive instead from that machine. This change is machine specific. You will need to do this to all PC's you intend to access 192.168.1.20 using the name Nasdrive (in this example). You can change the IP address and hostname to what you need them to be.

Comment: I think this is probably the best and easiest way for OP to implement what he's asked. No need for DNS and all of that.

Comment: After having had to manually update `/etc/hosts` on 40 machines yesterday, "easiest" quite depends on the network's size.

Comment: @grawity batch file on a file server... `echo 192.168.1.20 Nasdrive >> /etc/hosts` then telnet/ssh into each one...

Answer (score 8):

Addresses that use words aren't "IPs" or "IP addresses". (An [IPv4 address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address#IPv4_addresses) is four-byte and usually written as four decimal numbers; an [IPv6 address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address#IPv6_addresses) as 16 bytes usually written in hexadecimal.)

They might be called [hostnames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname) or [domain names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_name) (it varies; "domain name" kinda implies that it's accessible globally, not just within your local network). On the global internet, the [DNS protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) is used to translate such names to IP addresses, so "DNS name" is another possible term (although rare).

If you want the name to work only in your home network, dig into the configuration screen of your router – it will most likely have an option called "local domain" or "local hostnames" or "internal DNS" or something like that.

Another option is various local name resolution protocols – Windows has NBNS and LLMNR built in, to automatically translate `computername` to an IP address; OS X uses mDNS for names like `computername.local`; Linux can use either mDNS (via avahi-daemon) or NBNS (via Samba's nmbd).

If you want a name that's accessible globally, your pretty much the only option is to buy a domain name from one of the several hundred registrars (Dynadot, Namecheap, etc., etc., etc.)

Comment: There is also the option to host a local DNS server using standard DNS applications as BIND, maraDNS, PowerDNS, amongst many others.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Well, depending on the way one reads RFC 882, it did talk about domains as those having SOA and NS records (independent zones)... unlike domain _names_ maybe?

Comment: Hi would you be able to use a vpn to connect to my local hostnames globally (I dont really need to do this just wondered) ?

Comment: @user: Depends on how you set up both the hostname and the VPN. Corporate VPNs are often configured to use the internal DNS servers that make the "local" domains accessible.